# Difficulty reading UserDefaults with Fastlane Snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, snapshot, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane

I'm using [Fastlane's](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) [`snapshot`](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/snapshot) to create screenshots for an app I'm about to submit to the App Store.

It works "as advertised" for the most part, but it doesn't seem to like the way I access the `UserDefaults` within my app. On one test, it generates an **Exit status: 65** error.

`UI Testing Failure - com.me.MyApp crashed in (extension in MyApp):__ObjC.NSObject.defaultTime () -> Swift.Float`

I find `UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "defaultTime")` to an invitation for a syntax error, so I created an extension to access `UserDefaults`. Here's what the extension looks like:

```
class CustomExtensions: NSObject {
    /*
     This is blank. Nothing else in here. No really...nothing else
     */
}

extension NSObject {
    // User Defaults    
    func defaultTime() -> Float {
        return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "defaultTime") as! Float
    }

    // a bunch of other UserDefaults    
}
```

Wihin the app, whenever I need `defaultTime`, I just type `defaultTime()`. Using this method to access `UserDefaults` values works fine in the Simulator and on the devices I've tested. I only encounter a problem with `snapshot`.

I've tried adding in `sleep(1)` within the test, but that doesn't seem to do anything. I welcome suggestions re: alternative means of accessing `UserDefaults` that enable me to access them easily throughout MyApp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's probably happening is that, in your simulator and on device, you're writing a value to user defaults for the key `defaultTime` before it is ever read. `value(forKey:` returns an optional, and if you force-unwrap it (or force down-cast as your are doing here), you will crash if the value is nil. Try either returning an optional:

```
func defaultTime() -> Float? {
    return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "defaultTime") as? Float
}
```

or using a default value:

```
func defaultTime() -> Float {
    return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "defaultTime") as? Float ?? 0.0
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I was just reading about `nil coalescing operator`s here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-userdefaults. That resolved this issue, now I gotta tweak my test to click the right cell...that should be a little easier :) Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, my initial defaults are set in `AppDelegate.swift`. That your solution resolved my issue tells me UI Tests skip over the AppDelegate. I never would have guessed that. Hopefully this comment someone further down the line.